# Cannot use an Excel function without errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large excel function which has worked for me in the past (we have been using this spreadsheet for over a year), but now it is not working.  Here is a subsection of the formula

```
=sum(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6,G7... ZX529,ZY827,ZZ912)
```

Why am I having this issue?

Comment: When you say "not working" does it give you an error like #VALUE, #NAME? does it just give the wrong result?

Comment: My guess is it is number of columns. Excel 2007 has max ~10000 columns.  Excel 2003 (saved as xls) has a max of 256 so excel wouldn't recognize the cells in a xls format.

Comment: @aStackOverflowUser then i think sonya shisha hit the mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you go all the way from A to ZZ, this means you are using 26*26 = 676 arguments.  The maximum number of arguments is 255.  Since you are using single cells, you should try just using simple addition (the "+" operator) instead of a function.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to continue to use SUM function, even if you have more than 255 discontiguous cells to sum. If you bracket together sets of cells as "unions" then those count as one argument only, e.g. This sum function uses just 2 arguments:

> =SUM(A1,(B2,C3,D4,E5,F6,G7))